# What is the probability of having at most 3 pumpkins?

Tags: probability, statistics

"Weight of a pumpkin in a certain shop lies between 2.7 and 3.2 kg. On the day of Halloween, pumpkins of weight more than 3 kg are kept in the vegetable section and pumpkins of weight less than 3 kg are kept in the decoration section. If there are 10 pumpkins in the shop at the time of opening then the probability that at most 3 pumpkins will end up in the decoration section is..."

So I figured out that the expected value of this distribution is 2.95, and the probability of getting a Halloween pumpkin would be 0.6. I assumed that the expected value of Halloween pumpkins would be 6, so I would have to find out the probability of 3 pumpkins assuming I'm supposed to get 6 on an average. Is this the correct approach for this problem?

Comment: Yes, the approach is correct so far (you want the probability of *at most* three pumpkins) but you haven't calculated anything yet. The point is, I'm not sure if you have the correct probability distribution that is to be used for this problem , from the information that you have told me.

Comment: Notice you want the probability of three or fewer decorative pumpkins (or one minus the probability of more than three pumpkins), not the probability of exactly three pumpkins.

Comment: (Fun fact: In Pennsylvania, USA, sales tax applies to pumpkins used just for decoration, but not to pumpkins used for food.)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer as per my understanding of the answer below, the specific case of decoration pumpkins would be a binomial distribution right? So we don't really need to care about E[X].

Comment: @ChromeSabre You're right : the mean doesn't matter, it's the distribution. If $X$ is the number of pumpkins in the decoration section then $X$ is binomial with $10$ trials and success probability $0.6$. You just need $\mathbb P(X \leq 3)$ which can be calculated using the p.m.f of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but I think a more efficient way to solve the problem would be to compute the probability that there are zero pumpkins in the decoration section plus the probability that there is one pumpkin in the decoration section plus the probability that there are two pumpkins in the decoration section plus the probability that there are three pumpkins in the decoration section.

The probability that any given pumpkin ends up in the decoration section is $\frac{3}{5}$.

Therefore, the probability that zero pumpkins end up in the decoration section is $\binom{10}{0} \cdot \frac{3}{5}^0 \cdot\frac{2}{5}^{10}$.

The probability that one pumpkin ends up in the decoration section is $\binom{10}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{5}^1\cdot \frac{2}{5}^9$.

The probability that two pumpkins end up in the decoration section is $\binom{10}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{5}^2\cdot \frac{2}{5}^8$.

The probability that three pumpkins end up in the decoration section is $\binom{10}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{5}^3\cdot \frac{2}{5}^7$.

The reason we multiply by these binomial coefficients is because of the way we can "order" the pumpkins that get put in the decoration section. For example, when we have one pumpkin, the pumpkin that ends up going in the decoration section could be the third pumpkin we weigh, or the fifth pumpkin. Overall, there are 10 different places in which the pumpkin could be put in the decoration section, so we multiply by 10. When we have 2 pumpkins in the decoration section, there are ultimately $\binom{10}{2}$ different ways that our pumpkins could end up in decorating. Maybe it's the first two pumpkins we weigh, or the third and last pumpkin, or fifth and seventh pumpkin, etc.

Comment: Got it! I was actually doing some similar calculations but I accidentally took 10C3 for all the cases...